# Cannot Resolve Fargo HDP5000 Badge Printer "Check Ribbon" Error 97

Tags: printing, printer, hid

I am having issues resolving a ribbon error on a Fargo badge printer. When we try to print a badge  once it starts printing black it throws an error and then the badge that ran through the printer gets spit out blank. The ribbons look good, no damage or anything. We ran a color print test and a calibration test and the badge printed just fine with no issues at all.

What I've done:

1. changed some settings in the driver and made sure there was write privileges
2. updated drivers and printer firmware

Let me know what you guys think!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search gave a number of websites with instructions for clearing your error.
Apart from the things you have already done, one of the main suggestions is [calibrating the ribbon sensor](https://www.alphacard.com/technical-support/printers/fargo-printers/hdp5000-support/how-to-calibrate-a-ribbon-sensor-on-a-hdp5000/). Go to Printing Preferences > Toolbox button > Calibrate Ribbon tab.

If that fails as well, the last suggestion is to call for service.